# Why does Meteorite say "smart.json changed.." every time?

Tags: meteor, meteorite

My small meteor project has this smart.json

```
{
  "packages": {
    "iron-router": {},
    "handlebar-helpers": {},
    "jqueryui": {},
    "npm": {}
  }
}
```

Every time I start the server with mrt run, I get a "smart.json changed.." message, and it reinstalls all the packages (or so it seems). I don't think I've done anything to change smart.json. Quite recently I think the atmosphere site has been very unstable and sometimes the packages never load, so I can't start the server.

Is there anything I can do to prevent the install?

Comment: Just FYI, the reason why this is a problem is that recent instability in the atmosphere site has taken the package server offline, and my team has been unable to start meteor in our workstations. It seems that atmosphere has stabilized now and I'll probably stop worrying about it, regardless of why it needless reinstalls the packages.

Comment: I've been seeing this for a few weeks now and I don't think it's related to instability at atmosphere.  My smart.lock doesn't change but still I get this message (and all packages reinstalled) every time I start mrt. That's really annoying...

Comment: In a project that is using mrt 0.7.0 and meteor 0.7.0.1, it still does this every time. This is annoying always, but on occasions when we need to work when atmosphere is not available by network, it is a showstopper. I would sure appreciate a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I have found the answer. My smart.json file had some packages with no version specified. When thats the case, I believe that meteorite always checks to see if there are new package versions available, which makes a lot of sense. When I added a specific version to the package, the behavior stopped.

E.G. changing from:

```
"jqueryui": { }
```

to:

```
"jqueryui": {
  "version": "1.10.4"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Meteorite will say `smart.json changed` and reinstall everything if it notices another file `smart.lock` does not  exist or is different from `smart.json`.

If the files are different is assumes smart.json has changed and will reinstall what would be different.

If you check your project directory make sure you can see a `smart.lock` file and if you don't see one after you run `mrt` check whether `mrt` has adequate permissions to create one.

Comment: My smart.lock file is quite a bit more verbose than smart.json. When you say "is different from smart.json", do you mean that literally?

Comment: They vary very slightly in that the smart.lock has the git ref (tag/branch and comitt) of the package, but nothing more than that.

Comment: Then, although not quite the same, if there is no change in smart.lock, and no change in smart.json, then it should not install all the packages all over again? I will test.